# Change iframe src to user inputted HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, textarea, src

As a small side project, I am working on a website designed to help people learn the basics of computer science at GCSE level (14-16 years old) and I would like to create a system similar to the TryIt editor by w3schools. I would like to have a textarea, iframe and button set up so that when the user enters HTML code into the textarea and presses the button, the iframe will display the resultant webpage. For example, let's say the user enters this into the textarea:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Hello World.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then they press the button, and the iframe displays:

```
Hello World.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your web page would be a heaven for malicious coders.

Answer (score 0):

I was bored so I dug deeper into the code and got rid of some pointless stuff you probably wouldn't need.

Here is my updated answer::

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitTryit() {
  var text = document.getElementById("textareaCode").value;
  var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");
  ifr.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
  ifr.setAttribute("id", "iframeResult");  
  document.getElementById("iframewrapper").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("iframewrapper").appendChild(ifr);
  var ifrw = (ifr.contentWindow) ? ifr.contentWindow : (ifr.contentDocument.document) ? ifr.contentDocument.document : ifr.contentDocument;
  ifrw.document.open();
  ifrw.document.write(text);  
  ifrw.document.close();
}
</script>
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper1">
        <div class="headerText">Edit This Code:</div>
            <button class="seeResult" type="button" onclick="submitTryit()">See Result &raquo;</button>
 </div>
 <div class="textareawrapper">
        <textarea autocomplete="off" class="code_input" id="textareaCode" wrap="logical" spellcheck="false">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World
</body>
</html>
        </textarea>
        <form autocomplete="off" style="margin:0px;display:none;">
            <input type="hidden" name="code" id="code" />
            <input type="hidden" id="bt" name="bt" />
        </form>
 </div>
    <div class="iframecontainer">
        <div class="iframe">
         <div class="headerText">Result:</div>
         <div id="iframewrapper" class="iframewrapper">
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
<script>submitTryit()</script>
```

Hopefully this is on the lines of what you want

Comment: Not quite, I want to create something similar to the TryIt Editor, not just use it, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Updated the answer, also if you want the result to appear onload of the page insert '<script>submitTryit()</script>' at the end of the html markup

Comment: @Mr1flapjack1 I updated my answer a 3rd time, so disregard the comment above. In the new answer I made the script run off load.